# Can I match a Box<T> and still use it after?

Tags: rust

On the example below, I have to match over a `Box<Event>`, only to recreate a `Box` later

```
enum Event {
    Profile(String)
}

fn send(event: Box<Event>) {
    let mut events = Vec::new();
    match *event {
        Event::Profile(profile_event) => {
            events.push(Box::new(Event::Profile(profile_event)));
        },
        _ => {
            //error!("unknown event: {:?}", event);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6000667d42c8aac61ac4ca35e079ada4)

Is there a way to match a `Box` and still use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the matching itself, it comes from the fact that you're moving `profile_event` out of the enum variant. It compiles fine if you don't do that:

```
fn send(event: Box<Event>) {
    let mut events = Vec::new();
    match *event {
        Event::Profile(..) => {
            events.push(event)
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```